# correlation range between y and two variables x1 and x2

Tags: regression, correlation, linear-model, r-squared

What is the correlation coefficient (or range) $corr(y,\hat{y})$ for the regression $\hat{y}=ax_1+bx_2+c$ given that the correlation between $x_1$ and $y$ is 0.5 and the correlation between $x_2$ and $y$ is 0.5,and the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is 0. And what about the $R^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector of $n$ ground truth values $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector of predicted values $\mathbf{\hat{y}}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, you can write the covariance between the predictions and the ground truth as the dot product $\mathbf{\hat{y}}^\intercal \mathbf{y}$ (we suppose that the data is centered around zero to simplify the notations).

Then if you replace $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ by $a\mathbf{x_1} +b\mathbf{x_2}$ you may notice that the covariance of the prediction with your ground truth is simply the sum of the individual covariances, which is also true for the correlation :

$\mathbf{\hat{y}}^\intercal \mathbf{y} = (a\mathbf{x_1} +b\mathbf{x_2} )^\intercal y = (a\mathbf{x_1})^\intercal y + (b\mathbf{x_2})^\intercal y.$

To be specific, in your case, the correlation is 1.

Comment: But for the correlation, we don't have $corr(y,x_1+x_2)=corr(y,x_1)+corr(y,x_2)$. And why the answer is 1, why $a$ and $b$ are not included?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, without loss of generality, all data are standardised into z-scores. The data generating equation for y can then be written as:

$y = b_1*x_1 + b_2*x_2 + e $

using more common notation. We do not need the intercept now, which is zero for z-scores. Because the predictors are uncorrelated z-scores, there regression coefficients $b_1$ and $b_2$ are equal to the correlations of $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $y$, respectively, which is 0.5. That is, without controlling for $x_2$, the regression effect of $x_1$ would be equal to the correlation 0.5, but controlling for $x_2$ does not change this, since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are uncorrelated. So the above equation actually reads:

$y = 0.5*x_1 + 0.5*x_2 + e $

The explained variance of $y$ can be easily derived from this equation, namely the variance of the part $0.5*x_1 + 0.5*x_2$ and this is:

$var(0.5*x_1 + 0.5*x_2) = 0.5^2var(x_1) + 0.5^2*var(x_2) = 0.25 + 0.25 = 0.5$

Remember that because we use z-scores, the variances of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $y$ are all equal to 1. So, the R-square or proportion of variance explained is 0.5/1 = 0.5.

The above explanation was in terms of "population" data or the underlying data generating proces. It can also be done in terms of the usual sample estimates of proportion of explained variance, but the above is more straightforward.

Your question can be generalised to more uncorrelated $x$ variables, each having a particular correlation, say 0.5, with $y$. With three predictors the R square would be 0.75, and with four predictors, the R-square would be 1 (you can verify the results in the R script which follows below). Notice that a total of four predictors would suffice to explain all the variation in the $y$ values. Each predictors "eats" a different slice of the $y$ piza. Five predictors would be too much, and at least two of them would have to share (part of) a slice, meaning that these "sharing" predictors would have to be correlated.

Given the R square, you can take its square root to obtain the correlation of $y$ and $\hat{y}$. So for your question the correlation is $\sqrt{0.5}=0.71$.

Below is an R script showing the above. Look at the increase of the R square from value 0.25 with only $x_1$ to value 1 with four predictors. I used multivariate normal data for the simulation, but that is irrelevant.

```
library(MASS)

R <- matrix(c(1,   0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
              0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
              0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
              0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
            nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

mu <- c(y=0, x1=0, x2=0, x3=0, x4=0)
da <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n, mu = mu, Sigma = R))
cor(da)

m1 <- lm(y ~ x1, da)
summary(m1)
m2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, da)
summary(m2)
m3 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, da)
summary(m3)
m4 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, da)
summary(m4)
```

The correlation matrix and the results from the four model summaries are:

```
> cor(da)
           y           x1           x2           x3           x4
y  1.0000000  0.505480613  0.494140962  0.497895340  0.510316320
x1 0.5054806  1.000000000  0.009306463 -0.011101545  0.018293801
x2 0.4941410  0.009306463  1.000000000 -0.007057982 -0.007070375
x3 0.4978953 -0.011101545 -0.007057982  1.000000000  0.013342555
x4 0.5103163  0.018293801 -0.007070375  0.013342555  1.000000000
> 
> m1 <- lm(y ~ x1, da)
> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1, data = da)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.012437   0.008651   1.438    0.151    
x1          0.508223   0.008676  58.578   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8651 on 9998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2555,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2554 
F-statistic:  3431 on 1 and 9998 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> m2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, da)
> summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = da)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.007538   0.007125   1.058     0.29    
x1          0.503643   0.007146  70.482   <2e-16 ***
x2          0.492865   0.007156  68.871   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7125 on 9997 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4951,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.495 
F-statistic:  4901 on 2 and 9997 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> m3 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, da)
> summary(m3)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = da)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.003200   0.004994  -0.641    0.522    
x1           0.509269   0.005008 101.698   <2e-16 ***
x2           0.496416   0.005015  98.988   <2e-16 ***
x3           0.506719   0.004978 101.796   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4993 on 9996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7521,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.752 
F-statistic: 1.011e+04 on 3 and 9996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> m4 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, da)
> summary(m4)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = da)
   
Coefficients:
                    Estimate       Std. Error        t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.0000000005734  0.0000000004651         -1.233    0.218    
x1           0.5000000001340  0.0000000004665 1071907311.668   <2e-16 ***
x2           0.5000000002483  0.0000000004671 1070514855.619   <2e-16 ***
x3           0.4999999997962  0.0000000004636 1078423356.047   <2e-16 ***
x4           0.5000000001414  0.0000000004658 1073520245.720   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0000000465 on 9995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.162e+18 on 4 and 9995 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```